# Tried counting depth of brackets using array and not stack

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, brackets

The function is to count depth of brackets and return the position of maximum and earliest depth.

```
enter code here

#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int  n = 0, i =0, count = 0, maxi = 0, index = 0;
    string str;
    cout << "Enter n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the brackets";
    cin >> str;
    while (n--) {

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (str[i] == 1) {
                count = 0;
                while (str[i] != 2) {
                    count++;
                    i++;
                }
                if (count > maxi) {
                    maxi = count;
                    index = i - count;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    cout << "depth= " << maxi << endl << "starting index=" << index;
    return 0;
}
```

//not sure what went wrong with logic.. I counted the open brackets and as soon closed bracket appears, count stops and the index no. and count is passed. PS 1 means open bracket and 2 means closed bracket.

Comment: First of all, will the string always be equal (or shorter) in length than `n`? Secondly, what efforts at *debugging* have you made? Have you tried to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: string will be exactly equal to 'n'. I use to visual studios so it tells all the warning and errors. Its a live compiler. It just gives me wrong output

Comment: A comparison like `str[i] == 1` doesn't make sense. `str` is a string of *characters*. And supposedly a string of "bracket" characters and not digit characters. And what with `while (n--)`? What sense does that make if `n` is supposed to be the length of the string? The whole algorithm just seems off.

Comment: Are different kinds of brackets allowed? If not, why is a data structure needed? (Just keep track of the brackets currently open and the current "best match". If you encounter an opening bracket, increment the bracket count, if you encounter a closing bracket, update the best match, if necessary, and decrement the bracket count...

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulty in understanding you logic, and therefore jump into some of my own intepretation.

- I make `n` the number of strings to be input.
- Each string use `str.size()` to get the length for testing.
- Change you '1' to '<' and '2' to '>', thinking that you are finding the length between `<..>`.
- move the output inside the while loop `n`, simply for easies to observe, you may bring this line back to the end of the program. It won'e change the execution.

The code I changed to:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 using namespace std;
 int main() {
    int  n = 0, i =0, count = 0, maxi = 0, index = 0;
    string str;
    char bra='<', key='>';  // change the delimiters
    cout << "Enter test runs : n = ";
    cin >> n;               // assume n the number of test runs
    while (n--)
        {
          cout << "Enter the brackets : ";
          cin >> str;

          for (i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {  //use str.size();
          if (str[i] == bra) {

                count = 0;
                while (str[++i] != key) { count++; }
                if (count > maxi) {
                    maxi = count;
                    index = i - count;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "depth= " << maxi << endl << "starting index = " << index <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A test:

```
$ ./a.exe
Enter test runs : n = 2
Enter the brackets : First<1234>second<1234567>end1
depth= 7
starting index = 18
Enter the brackets : Thrid<123456789>forth<12345>end2
depth= 9
starting index = 6
```